# Plot mask on top of grayscale image MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, grayscale

I'm running an algorithm to segment part of an image using morphological operations. 
I end up with a 2D binary image that represents the segmentation results. Namely, the mask. My question is how to plot the original image and the mask overlay in color on top of it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`imoverlay`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10502-image-overlay) written by Steve Eddins.

In addition, you can check these blog posts by him:

- [Image visualization using transparency](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/08/20/image-visualization-using-transparency/)
- [Image overlay using transparency](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/02/18/image-overlay-using-transparency/)

Comment: So, you can click the little accept mark on the answer to officially mark that this solved your problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `imoverlay` is fine, I do so myself, but often I want a transparent composite. It's convenient to have this in a single array as it makes saving the image a bit easier.

```
alpha = repmat(0.35 * mask,[1 1 3]);
labels = label2rgb(bwlabel(mask));
im3 = repmat(im,[1 1 3]); %# Assuming image is grayscale
overlay = ( (1-alpha) .* im3 ) + ( alpha .* labels );
imshow(overlay); %# Or imwrite, etc.
```

Comment: in the future I will be plotting a composite, this will be very helpful, thank you.

Comment: Just finished some composite plots, your code was very helpful. I also found this: [link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34936) that uses a similar principle. Thought it may be helpful.